# Excel custom ribbon UI gallery?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office, ribbon

Is it possible to create this custom ribbon ui part? Is it a gallery control?

[image]

Comment: I can say it's not a gallery (see example image of a gallery in the [RibbonX docs for gallery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-customui/017f9f94-700f-4846-ba19-c695ad32929f)) ... but I can't definitively tell you what it is ... other than AFAIK you can't create it with RibbonX (hoping someone will prove me wrong ...)